# How to properly store cubed carrots?

Tags: storage, carrots

Should cubed carrots be stored in a water or just as they are.  I've seen it done both ways, so I would like to know which way is correct and why.

These cubed carrots end up going in a farmer's chop salad.

They are made quickly by peeling raw carrots and then cubing them.

**Related Posts:**

[White Film on Carrots](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/49066/what-is-the-white-film-on-my-wet-carrots?rq=1)

[Storing Carrots](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15517/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-carrots?rq=1)

Comment: I'm not a professional (and thus, don't have to deal with health codes).  If I were doing it, I'd try to keep a damp towel over them to prevent evaporation but keep them from being soaked (which will affect how the dressing adheres).  Another alternative might be a lid for it.

Comment: @Joe damp towels in contact with food would be a health code violation in many countries?

Comment: "Properly" for health certification reasons would depend when you live, properly for best flavour and colour etc, would require cold and humidity, again depends where you live

Comment: Check local restaurant health code.

Comment: @cadegalt You may be able to find some helpful information on this page: http://www.nyc.gov/html/doh/html/environmental/food-service.shtml

Comment: @TFD I have no idea.  I'd be concerned with someone not simply lifting the towel and retrieving stuff, and placing it somewhere unsafe then back onto the carrots -- a lid would have much less contact

Answer (score 1):

The cubed carrots should be placed like the image. It should not be kept in water as the flavour of the carrots will decrease with time. I have noticed that the long term exposure of carrots to water will soften them but with some noticeable change in the taste.

Further, to keep the carrots really fresh you can use the same technique, simply wet a piece of cloth (preferably cotton), squeeze to loose 70% of water in it and then cover your carrots. The freshness and the taste; everything will be maintained for sure.